# bucle infinito, bloqueo de interfaz android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo un problema con un blucle infinito que genero en un handler, la idea del bucle infinito es que espere a que se presione un boton que modifica el valor de p, pero el tema es este cuando entra en el bucle infinito se bloquea la interfaz y no me permite presionar ninguno de los 4 botones 
me dijeron que con un new thread antes del handler se solucionaria el problema pero no fue asi, tal vez lo puse mal si alguien me puede dar una solucion se lo agradeceria.

```
public void iniciarTimer() {
c=0;
encender=true;
n = 0;
generar();
final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                numero = list.get(n);
                if (encender == true) {
                    if (finalizar == false) {
                        switch (numero) {
                            case 1:

                                boton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                boton3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                                boton2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
                                boton4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.amarillo);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                boton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                boton3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                                boton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
                                boton4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.amarillo);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                boton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                boton2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
                                boton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
                                boton4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.amarillo);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                boton4.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                boton3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                                boton2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
                                boton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
                                break;
                        }
//condicion para que aumente n +1 despues de la primer pasada del handler ya que el primer color lo prende en la segunda pasada
                        if (c != 0) {
                            n++;
                        }
                        c++;
//limite de puntos en el juego
                        if (n > 10) {
                            finalizar = true;
                            encender = false;
                            fin();
                        }
//en nivel dificil que valla aumentando la velocidad
                        dificil = nivel;
                        if (dificil == 750) {
                            nivel = (nivel - 10);
                        }
// una vez que se recorre la lista que entre en el if para comparar
                        if (n == list.size()) {
// recorrer la lista
                            for (a = (0); a < (list.size()); a++) {
// esperar un valor de p al presionar un boton.
                                p = 0;
                                if (p == 0) {
                                    a--;
                                }
// comparar si el boton presionado coincide con el de la lista de no ser asi que finalize la activity
                                if (p != 0) {
                                    if (list.get(a) != p) {
                                        encender = false;
                                        finalizar = true;
                                        fin();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
// si todos los botones coiniciden inicia el timer de vuelta para generar otro numero y arrancar a recorrer de 0
                            encender = false;

                        }
                        if (encender == true) {
                            if (finalizar == false) {
                                handler.postDelayed(this, nivel);
                            }
                        } else {
//suma el punto si todos los botones coinciden y reinicia el timer para generar otro numero y arrancar a recorrer de 0
                            sumar();
                            apagar();
                            iniciarTimer();
                        }
                    } else {
                        apagar();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
}).start();
}
```

Comment: Los threads no hacen "magia", si deseas hacer alguna tarea cuando se presione algun boton  debes usar `onClickListener`

Comment: el onclicklisterner existe, pero aun asi no funciona la interfaz queda congelada, es como que entra en el bucle y muere ahi aun que aprete no pasa nada. el onclicklistener lo tengo declarado, y en las pruebas poniendo p=list.get(a) pude comprar que el onclick funcionaba perfectamente

Comment: Siempre deja un delay en los threads

Comment: Y trata de simplificar tu código, complica y marea al leerlo.

Comment: si yo ya me acostumbre a verlo pero es un quilombo importante. el programa en si ya lo termine pero de otra manera queria saber si habia alguna forma de que esta manera funcione

Comment: mmmm... Usar los hilos sin saber manejarlos es peligroso, siempre tienes que usarlos para tareas que no involucren la parte gráfica ya que esta se encuentra en el hilo principal y la comunicación conlleva gastos de recursos. Los hilos se usan para tareas que consuman demasiado tiempo, por ejemplo, descargar imagenes, hacer cálculo pesado, etc, y solo tienes que enviar el resultado al hilo principal. Depurar cuando programas con hilos es tedioso ya que no sigue las tareas de forma secuancial aparentenmente

Comment: si, no se mucho del tema soy muy nuevo en esto de android, pero bueno a medida que lo hacia me iban surgiendo problemas y los solucionaba hasta que llego este pero por lo visto es una solucion avanzada para mi en este momento. el programa es un quilombo y seguramente  poco eficiente pero como no piden que sea eficiente el programa sino que funcione no me preocupe y segui...

Comment: Los Hilos o Threads son cuestiones de todos los SO, por lo que la mayoria de lenguajes de programación las implementa, asi si has usado otro lenguaje de programación anteriormente habras escuchado del tema sino lo tienes que aprender :P, Otro punto es que hacer un sofware por hacer no es una buena practica, es poco mantenible, que funcione una vez no implica que alguna vez no falle, cuando hable que gastaba recursos no solo me referia a memoria, sino que esto conlleva a que el software tenga muchos en un futuro, quizas hoy no, pero mañana sí, como ahora donde tu software es inmantenible.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?